# Qt - Switching from shared build to static build? (VS 2005)

Tags: visual-studio-2005, qt4

The situation is this: I have a shared (DLL) build of [Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(toolkit)) 4.5.1 and some reasons given by the project lead, I have to convert to Qt 4.5.2 static. I am using the Qt Visual Studio plug-in to manage my project.

1) Would DLLs ([Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) 5.2 and other Qt solutions) compiled with the shared Qt 4.5.1 work with an [EXE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXE) compiled with static Qt 4.5.2, or do I have to re-complie all those third party DLLs?

2) Is it possible to compile a DLL from a static build?

3) Are there any additional dependencies for a static build of an existing Qt 4.5 solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We compile our app ->debug as dynamic and ->release as static in order to prevent users from dll hell in Windows and using one file only.
1) We compiled both versions of all libraries. As release=static and debug=dynamic, like our own app.

2) Not that I can imagine.

3) Not that I can imagine.